# speed up program by doing operation inside or outside of loop

Tags: performance, optimization, loops, fortran, bigdata

I just have a question of fortran optimisation (probably programs in general):

There are two ways to carry out a basic operation, over the entire vector or row by row, i.e.

```
x = array(:,1)
y = array(:,2)
z = array(:,3)

x1 = floor(x/k) + 1
y1 = floor(y/k) + 1
z1 = floor(z/k) + 1
```

OR

```
do i = 1:n
   x1(i) = floor(x(i)/k) + 1
   y1(i) = floor(y(i)/k) + 1
   z1(i) = floor(z(i)/k) + 1
end do
```

I can do openmp on the loop because there are 100 million entries but I'm not sure it would hlep. Would it be faster to do it in the loop or outside of the loop. Experience and common sense tells me to do it outside. There are other components to the program but I'm finding most of the time is taken up by creating new vectors x1,y1,z1 because there are so many x,y,z values to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned with execution speed then I suggest you profile a version of the code which dispenses with what seem to be the temporary array slices `x`,`y`, and `z`.  Creating them will require copying a lot of stuff around the memory of your machine. You could simply write

```
x1 = floor(array(:,1)/k) + 1
y1 = floor(array(:,2)/k) + 1
z1 = floor(array(:,3)/k) + 1
```

Your compiler ought to be able to do this without making a copy of `array` but this is something you ought to check.

Depending on elements of your code which are not shown in your question you might even be able to declare `x1`,`y1` and `z1` to be pointers and write something like this:

```
array_over_k = floor(array/k) + 1
x1 => array_over_k(:,1)
y1 => array_over_k(:,2)
z1 => array_over_k(:,3)
```

Whichever way you do the calculations you still gotta do the calculations, but do you need to make all those copies of elements of the arrays ?

Comment: Since you've got the profiler fired up, see if multiplying by 1/k is faster than dividing - a smart compiler should do that for you, but it's always best to check.

Answer (score 0):

This will be memory bandwidth bound. I would go the first way, if they are separate in memory (i.e. not some weird non-contiguous pointers). But it's best to try and measure, without profiler one can be wrong easily. Also, you can do OpenMP or just autoparallelization for the first version as well.